# Where to do clean up in a usercontrol?

Tags: vb.net, events, user-controls, dispose

I have created a usercontrol in VB.NET.

From within this usercontrol, I am playing a (perhaps longer) sound via a call to the API function `mciSendString`.

I would like to cancel the playing using another API call to `mciSendString` when the usercontrol is destroyed (because the hosting form is destroyed).

However, it is not clear to me where this should be done in the usercontrol.

Is the under given code the place where I should do this? If not, then where should it be done?

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Dispose method is where you should perform cleanup.  Just be aware that it's possible that the Dispose method of a control will not be called until later than you think, e.g. a form displayed by calling ShowDialog will not be disposed when it is closed but must be disposed explicitly, so a dialogue that gets reused will not dispose its controls in between.

Comment: Thank you. Where would you stop the playing of sounds in my case? I really don't want to call something like Me.SomeControl.StopSounds in my form. It sounds fishy to me. I would really like to let everything be handled automatically and not externally. I hope I could express it well.

Comment: That really depends on what behaviour you want.  If you just want to stop the sounds when the control is disposed then do it in the Disposed method.  You might also want to handle the VisibleChanged event of the control's parent form and stop the sounds when the form is hidden.